# How do I link and excel slicer to an excel slider (scroll bar)?

Tags: vba, scrollbar, excel-2010, pivot-table

Excel 2010 have a PivotTable feature called a slicer. Slicers are nice. However, when your slicing on a column with tons of unique values, slicers suck.

I want to know how to tie a slicer to a "slider" (scroll bar), that way I can link a Macro to the Scroll bar that selects all Slicer values less than or equal  to the value on the scroll bar. When I change the scroll bar by clicking, the value changes and thus the selected values of the slicer change.

Answer (score 4):

Found a way to do this and avoid the middle man (the slicer). This may have to do with how my own particular data is structured, but I think it will work in general.

1. Using the Macro Recorder, record yourself setting a value filter on the column you want to have a slicer on. In my case the column is `% of Sales with Vendor`
   We use Value Filters -> Greater Than. Select the column, then input the value. Your pivot table will change. Stop the Macro Recorder.
2. We need another piece of code. Record a new Macro. With this Macro, clear the filter you just set on the pivot table, then stop the Recorder.
3. Developer -> Insert -> Scroll Bar. Just put the scroll bar anywhere for now.
4. Enter a value in the range of values of `% of Sales with Vendor` into a cell like A1. While my pivot table shows the data as a percentage, the underlying source uses decimals. For 20%, I will enter 2. Why? You CANNOT scroll bar on non-integer values. I really want 0.2 but by entering `=A1/10` in an adjacent cell, I can always reference the value I really want
5. You need to create one macro only (from the two you recorded) that looks like this.

---

```
Sub sliderfilter()  
    '  
    ' sliderfilter Macro  
    '  
    '  

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Vendor"). _  
    ClearAllFilters  

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Vendor").PivotFilters. _  
        Add Type:=xlValueIsGreaterThan, DataField:=ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _  
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("% of Sales with Vendor"), Value1:=Range("B1").Value

End Sub
```

6. A1 is where you had the value `2`. The Scroll bar should have Cell Link $A$1. However, you Macro reference B1... the place where you divide by ten to be in the proper range of the `% of Sales with Vendor` values.
7. Of course, you assign the macro to the Scroll bar.

When you change the scroll bar, it changes A1, and B1, and tells the Macro to execute a Value Filter, using the value in B1. You have thus created a SLIDER, because no you can just click or slide through the scroll bar values (PS. A scroll bar with the long edge horizontal, is a slider)

Comment: Works beautifully, thanks. Just to add that the slider needs to be configured also, setting the reference cell and the range.